# Table not importing values from array (Handlebars/html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, handlebars.js

I have created a handlebar template for a table which imports data from the following array.

```
let all_units = [
    {
        'code': 'COMP2110',
        'title': 'Web Technology', 
        'offering': 'S1'
    },  
    {
        'code': 'COMP2010',
        'title': 'Algorithms and Data Structures', 
        'offering': 'S1'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2150',
        'title': 'Game Design', 
        'offering': 'S1'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2320',
        'title': 'Offensive Security', 
        'offering': 'S1'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2200',
        'title': 'Data Science', 
        'offering': 'S2'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2250',
        'title': 'Data Communications', 
        'offering': 'S2'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2300',
        'title': 'Applied Cryptography', 
        'offering': 'S2'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2000',
        'title': 'Object-Oriented Programming Practices', 
        'offering': 'S2'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2050',
        'title': 'Software Engineering', 
        'offering': 'S2'
    },
    {
        'code': 'COMP2100',
        'title': 'Systems Programming', 
        'offering': 'S2'
    }
];
```

This is the my handlebar template on main html page.

```
        <script id="Unit_List" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th> Code </th>
            <th> Title </th>
            <th> Offering </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {{#each unit}}
                <th> {{code}} </th>
                <th> {{title}} </th>
                <th> {{offering}} </th>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>

        </table>


        </script>
```

This is the view function on a javascript page that is supposed to display the table.

```
function unit_table(id, units) {
    let target = document.getElementById(id);
    let table = "<table>";

    let template= Handlebars.compile(
                                      document.getElementById("Unit_List").textContent     
                                      );
    table=template({'units': units});
    console.log(table);




    table += "</table>";
    target.innerHTML = table;
}
```

However the handlebar template fails to import the values from the array into the table . It displays just the heading rows without the values. There might be something wrong with the handlebars initialisation.
I've made sure all the functions are imported and exported properly.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I really couldn't find out where did you pass `all_units` as `unit` to your handlebar template.

Comment: I have a function in the main js file. ```window.onload = function() {
    unit_table("content", all_units);```

Comment: Your template tries to iterate each `unit` (singular), but the call to your template function uses `units` (plural) as the identifier.